# Asp.Net MVC Code First : Populate drop down options from different database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a form with three fields Company(select list), Area (select list), and Detail (input box). Company list options are being populated from Company Table (Possible values are CompanyXX and CompanyYY) of Main Database (MasterDb).

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="" />
    <add name="CompanyXX"  connectionString="" />
    <add name="CompanyYY" connectionString=" />    
  </connectionStrings>

public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [KeyAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Area
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to populate Area select list from different database based on company Selected. For example if I select CompanyXX in drop down, it should pick another connection string from web.config (each company has its own connection string in database) and get list of areas from that database. I can do ajax calls to dynamically load areas list from same database but not from different database. Can you please help? Is this possible to change connection string dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you have same database structure in all different database. In this way you have to just pass the connection string name while creating the DbContext object for making the query.

```
  if(CompanyXX) 
    {
     YouDbContext context = new YourDbContext("CompanyXX");
     var areas = context.Areas.All();
    }

    else if(CompanyYY)
    {
     YouDbContext context = new YourDbContext("CompanyYY");
     var areas = context.Areas.All();
     }
```

make sure that you have set your connection string names in web.config accordingly.

---

Other case, if you have different database structure, you have to create three different entity framework data model(.edmx files).